# Overlay scrollBar on chrome is no longer working after the latests updates

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar, overlay

I have a question about the overlay scrollBar, after the lastest update on chrome, we can no longer use it "[Overlay-Chrome](https://caniuse.com/css-overflow-overlay#:%7E:text=The%20overlay%20value%20of%20the,as%20the%20scrollbar-gutter%20property)"
Is there any other way to develop a personalized overlay scrollbar on chrome with css or javascript, I need some advices about the subject

Thanks in advance,